# What exactly does 'thrown' mean in terms of OOP

Tags: oop

I am new to OOP and I keep seeing `error is thrown..` `runtime exception is thrown..`

From my understanding, anything after `throw` is not executed if some condition is true.

But what does a sentence like this mean

`an error is thrown when the program executes`

Comment: Do you have a peace of code to show an example? Are you talking about exeptions?

Answer (score 0):

When an error occurs within a method, the method creates an object and hands it off to the runtime system. The object, called an **exception object**, contains information about the error, including its type and the state of the program when the error occurred. Creating an exception object and handing it to the runtime system is called throwing an exception.

After the exception is thrown it can be handeled by the apropriate handler. An exception handler is considered appropriate if the type of the exception object thrown matches the type that can be handled by the handler.

So the term **thrown** means that, the system has just completed process of throwing an exception and now it can be handled by any handler we progarmmed .

Answer (score 0):

From **Matt Weisfeld** - *Advanced Object-Oriented Concepts*
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2026020&seqNum=2

> If an exception is thrown within the try block, the catch block will handle it. When an exception is thrown while the block is executing, the following occurs:
>
> 1. The execution of the try block is terminated.
> 2. The catch clauses are
>    checked to determine whether an appropriate catch block for the
>    offending exception was included. (There might be more than one
>    catch clause per try block.)
> 3. If none of the catch clauses handles
>    the offending exception, it is passed to the next higher-level try
>    block. (If the exception is not caught in the code, the system
>    ultimately catches it, and the results are unpredictable—that is, an
>    application crash.)
> 4. If a catch clause is matched (the first match
>    encountered), the statements in the catch clause are executed.
> 5. Execution then resumes with the statement following the try block.